# cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.IRenewableToken'

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

I am currenty creating SQLWorker class with various methods which excutes various sql commands as part of a wider framework. I have a method which is used to execute a sql scripts. as whon below:

```
public object ExecuteScript(string sql, ExecutionType executionType = ExecutionType.NonQuery,
        int statementTimeout = 1800)
    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.InfoMessage += (sender, args) =>
                _infoMessageText.AppendLine(args.Message);

            var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
            server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = statementTimeout;
            switch (executionType)
            {
                case ExecutionType.NonQuery:
                    return server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
                case ExecutionType.Scalar:
                    return server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteScalar(sql);
                case ExecutionType.Reader:
                    return server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteReader(sql);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am currently getting  the error:
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.IRenewableToken'

the particular line is

```
 var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
```

The ServerConnection Class seem to expect a parameter of IRenewableToken but it has constructor that accepts a SqlConnection parameter.

I am not sure what I missing I beleive I have the correct NugetPackages and have the following using statements

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
```

Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was solved by changing the using statement from using System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. I was refactoring an old version of code and they were using an older version of Microsoft.Sqlserver.Management.objects nuget package along with System.Data.SqlClient. With the latest version of Microsoft.Sqlserver.Management.objects it didnt work.